# É possível criar uma comunicação entre uma aplicação tkinter e uma pygame?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, jogos

Eu sei que `tkinter` não é *thread-safe*, mas sinceramente não sei ainda bem o que isso quer dizer. Estamos a criar um jogo com `pygame`, e gostaria de integrar um **menu** inicial e uma **console** escritos com tkinter, mas não sei se é possível, e se é uma boa ideia. 
Se é possível, como o posso fazer, e quais são as implicações e riscos que posso ter?

Answer (score 1):

**Não é possível** combinar as duas bibliotecas porque são bibliotecas gráficas com objetivos diferentes, para não dizer concorrentes entre si. É sim possível escrever um programa que crie tanto uma janela pygame quanto outra tkinter ao mesmo tempo, mas não o tkinter dentro do pygame, em tela cheia, por exemplo.

Seria gerado um erro se tentarmos dizer que o master de um frame do tkinter é a janela do pygame, porque o tipo esperado é diferente.

Se por um lado, o pygame tem muitas propriedades e funções que trabalham com a placa de vídeo da máquina, por outro requer que até o loop principal da aplicação seja implementado. Mesmo um simples clique de mouse precisa ter seu evento escutado para que, de fato, o clique exista na aplicação. Logo, o pygame não tem condições de ter um botão padrão como no tkinter, pois o clique não funcionaria. Neste ponto o pygame é mais primitivo: ele pede que o sistema operacional crie uma janela, e, dentro dela, ele assume toda a responsabilidade.

Em contrapartida, no tkinter, todos os eventos que o sistema operacional possui já são escutados pela aplicação, inclusive o loop principal existe, na função `mainloop()`. A aplicação só não reage porque não existe uma função de callback, feita pelo programador, com as instruções para cada um destes eventos. Por isso o tkinter pode se dar ao luxo de ter controles elaborados como botões, comboboxes, e outros, mas sempre se submetendo à todas as definições visuais padrões do sistema, como resolução de tela, coisa que o pygame não precisa fazer.

É possível implementar no tkinter algo pequeno, 2D e melhor ainda se for meio estático, como um jogo de xadrez por exemplo. Pode-se usar o canvas. Nesse caso recomendo estudar a técnica de *double buffer*.

Answer (score 1):

**Sim, é possível.** Ao menos é possível embutir o pygame no Tkinter.

Em algumas plataformas é possível embutir o display do pygame em uma janela já existente. Para fazer isso, a variável de ambiente `SDL_WINDOWID` deve ser setada com uma string contendo o `id` da janela.

A variável de ambiente é checada quando o display do pygame é inicializado. Mas fique atento, pois podem haver alguns efeitos estranhos quando rodar o pygame embutido em um outro display.

Aqui um exemplo:

```
import platform
import os
import pygame

#Assumindo que embed é um tk.Frame previamente criado
#Seta a id da janela (Windows ID)
os.environ['SDL_WINDOWID'] = str(embed.winfo_id())
#Seta o driver de vídeo caso for Windows
if platform.system == "Windows":
    os.environ['SDL_VIDEODRIVER'] = 'windib'
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((500,500))
screen.fill(pygame.Color(255,255,255))
pygame.display.init()
pygame.display.flip()
```

**Fontes:** Usuário do Stack [PythonNut](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23319059/embedding-a-pygame-window-into-a-tkinter-or-wxpython-frame) e [Documentação do Pygame](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html)